# In product page right sidebar gets misplaced after adding cms block

Tags: magento-1.9, cms-block, product-page

I used below code in local.xml to add the cms block at the end of the product content, but it will push the right sidebar down (2columns-right is the template)!

```
<catalog_product_view>            
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="cms/block" name="product-page-carousel" as="product-page-carousel" after="-">
                <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>product-page-carousel</block_id></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems some CSS issue. I am not much aware about CSS thing but other way you can use below line in `YOUR_THEME/template/catalog/product/view.phtml`

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('product-page-carousel')->toHtml();
```

Just move this block call in different position & set where it looks good.